# Winforms .NET: How to show something of a fixed size (in inches) on every screen/device

Tags: c#, winforms, screen

I need to show an image at 5 inches in height (e.g. you should be able to measure it with a physical ruler), no matter what monitor size or resolution or DPI you are using.

I guess I need the monitor physical size .. but I'm not sure you can get that on winforms

Any ideas?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16848779/62576) doesn't help?

Comment: What does "it doesn't seem to work in all screen resolutions" mean?  It is difficult to provide an answer to an unstated question.

Comment: @KenWhite yes it did, thank you! I posted the final solution as an answer to my questions.. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution! I'm posting it here in case someone runs into the same problem...

```
dim PixelsPerMMofScreen as double 

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    Dim monitorSizesMM As List(Of PointF) = GetDesktopMonitors()
    If monitorSizesMM.Count > 0 Then
        PixelsPerMMofScreen = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / monitorSizesMM(0).Y
    end if    

    Label1.Width = mm2px(50)
    Label1.Height = mm2px(50)
End Sub

Function mm2px(mm As Integer) As Integer
    Return mm * pixelsPerMMofScreen
End Function


Public Shared Function GetDesktopMonitors() As List(Of PointF)
    Dim screenSizeList As New List(Of PointF)()

    '''///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Try
        Dim searcher As New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("root\WMI", "SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorID")

        For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.[Get]()
            Debug.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------")
            Debug.WriteLine("WmiMonitorID instance")
            Debug.WriteLine("----------------")
            '   Console.WriteLine("Active: {0}", queryObj["Active"]);
            Debug.WriteLine("InstanceName: {0}", queryObj("InstanceName"))
            '   dynamic snid = queryObj["SerialNumberID"];
            '   Debug.WriteLine("SerialNumberID: (length) {0}", snid.Length);
            Debug.WriteLine("YearOfManufacture: {0}", queryObj("YearOfManufacture"))

            '
            '                foreach (PropertyData data in queryObj.Properties)
            '                {
            '                    Debug.WriteLine(data.Value.ToString());
            '                }
            '                


            Dim code As Object = queryObj("ProductCodeID")
            Dim pcid As String = ""
            For i As Integer = 0 To code.Length - 1
                'pcid = pcid +code[i].ToString("X4");
                pcid = pcid & [Char].ConvertFromUtf32(code(i))
            Next
            Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToString("ProductCodeID: ") & pcid)


            Dim xSize As Integer = 0
            Dim ySize As Integer = 0
            Dim PNP As String = queryObj("InstanceName").ToString()
            PNP = PNP.Substring(0, PNP.Length - 2)
            ' remove _0
            If PNP IsNot Nothing AndAlso PNP.Length > 0 Then
                Dim displayKey As String = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\"
                Dim strSubDevice As String = (displayKey & PNP) + "\" + "Device Parameters\"
                ' e.g.
                ' SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY\LEN40A0\4&1144c54c&0&UID67568640\Device Parameters
                ' SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY\LGD0335\4&1144c54c&0&12345678&00&02\Device Parameters
                '
                Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToString("Register Path: ") & strSubDevice)

                Dim regKey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(strSubDevice, False)
                If regKey IsNot Nothing Then
                    If regKey.GetValueKind("edid") = RegistryValueKind.Binary Then
                        Debug.WriteLine("read edid")

                        Dim edid As Byte() = DirectCast(regKey.GetValue("edid"), Byte())

                        Const edid_x_size_in_mm As Integer = 21
                        Const edid_y_size_in_mm As Integer = 22
                        xSize = (CInt(edid(edid_x_size_in_mm)) * 10)
                        ySize = (CInt(edid(edid_y_size_in_mm)) * 10)
                        Debug.WriteLine("Screen size cx=" + xSize.ToString() + ", cy=" + ySize.ToString())
                    End If
                    regKey.Close()
                End If
            End If

            Debug.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------")

            Dim pt As New PointF()
            pt.X = CSng(xSize)
            pt.Y = CSng(ySize)

            screenSizeList.Add(pt)
        Next
    Catch e As ManagementException
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message)
    End Try

    Return screenSizeList
End Function
```