# How to draw line with real world lenght and measure distance from another line?

Tags: .net, vb.net, draw

I need to draw some vertical lines on screen ( I display it on a monitor),
That lines must to be 1 inch from each one.
I also need to draw another line that user can move pressing arrows.
Once in final position I want to find the real distance in inches from the nearest line.
I'm able to draw line in winform, WPF and XNA, but how can I be sure that lines have a real world distance of 1 inches? And how can I measure the distance in inches?
Any advice?

Comment: see [Convert Pixels to Inches and vice versa in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474810/convert-pixels-to-inches-and-vice-versa-in-c-sharp)

Comment: To do this, you have to be able to guarantee the monitor dot pitch, resolution, and system zoom level, NONE of which are normally available.

Comment: @Étienne Laneville I'll try your suggestion.